# Cooking on Yom Tov, for Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz, cooking-bishul, eruv-tavshilin

Why can't one cook for the second day of Yom Tov on the first day? Why won't something along the lines of [Eiruv Tavshilin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2867/how-eruv-tavshilin-works/2870#2870) help in this case as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of a 2-day Yom Tov is a s'feika d'yoma.  If Thursday is the Yom Tov, I cannot cook for Friday which is Chol (Rosh Hashana isn't exactly because of the same reason, but the same answer would apply).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, as you're allowed to cook for the same day.

Comment: @SAH That same day is either Yom Tov or not. Either way you can cook for it.