# When Friday is last day of Chag - Can you bring shabbat in early, thus taking out chag early?

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov

For example in Israel this year the last day of Pesach is Friday.  I am looking for sources that discusses bringing in Shabbat after pesach early.  This would have the effect of ending pesach early - no yale veyavo in mariv etc.

I remember reading something about this, and Im guessing some say its ok and some say its not.  I am looking for sources discussing this if anyone can point me?

Comment: I believe the minhag in many places is to specifically do this so people don't accidentally cook on shabbos, since they were used to doing so on yom tov

Comment: do you have any sources/references I can look up?

Comment: Consider that you have to light shabbat candles before sunset, so at that point one is presumably ‘ending yom tov early’. Then it’s just a matter of degree

Comment: I believe this idea has been written about for 100s of years. Im looking for a source that I can read about.

Comment: You are not ending Pesach early, you are starting Shabbat early, and the kedusha of Shabbat is higher than Yom Tov. [This reputable site](https://dinonline.org/2012/06/10/making-early-yom-tov-on-shabbos/) notes (3rd para before last) that when Yom Tov falls on Friday, it is fine to make kiddush early while it is still Yom Tov.

Comment: You still can't eat chametz, though.

Comment: @robev I think you may be misremembering. The minhag to do this is so the cooking for shabbat will happen earlier in the day and the eruv tavshillin can work even for the opinion that requires Ho'il.

Comment: @N.T. Accd to the Taz 668 you might be able to.

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds better :)

Comment: @robev https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91157/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think it's comparable. Shemini Atzeres and Succos are incompatible; Shabbos and Pesach are not.

Comment: @N.T. The Taz there explicitly says Friday Yom Tov into Shabbat is an example of incompatible times (in his proof from what to mention in bentching).

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting. It does look like he is a da'as yachid.